# Error: '--allowJs' is not set while including custom CKEditor 5 build in Angular 5 project

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, ckeditor5

I have created a custom CKEditor build including [ckeditor5-simple-upload](https://github.com/pourquoi/ckeditor5-simple-upload). Now when I include the custom build in my component as:

```
import * as ClassicEditor from '../../ckeditor.js';
```

I get the error -

```
ERROR in src/app/core/foo-bar/foo-bar.component.ts(4,32): error TS6143: Module '../../ckeditor.js' was resolved to 'D:/my-project/src/app/ckeditor.js', but '--allowJs' is not set.
```

I tried `allowJS: true` in tsconfig.app.json, but it did not help.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it a typo?

It should be `allowJs: true`.